# UIbutton with multiple argument selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am coding in Xcode 6.1.1 and with objective-c.
I want to have multiple buttons who all call the same method.
Normally I would do something like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(button_method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What I would like to do is when I touch an button the button sends itself to a method. Something like this (**OF COURSE THIS IS WRONG**):

```
[button2 addTarget:self action:[button2 performSelector:@selector(method2:) withObject:button2] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And in the method do something like this:

```
-(void)add_group:(UIButton*)button{
  button.backgroundcolor=[UIColor greencolor];
```

}

Question: What would be the right way to call a method from a button with itself as argument?

Comment: What you're asking here is very basic knowledge about buttons. You need to spend some quality time with the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first idea is almost the best. When using the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method, the `action` parameter may - if you want - additionally include the sender automatically as said in the documentation:

> The action message may optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that order.

So simply keep your `add_group:` method as it is and make the following statement:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(add_group:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Your object `button` will than be automatically passed to the action method `add_group:`. Don't forget the colon!

Comment: I will try that out !! awesome

Answer (score 2):

`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` accepts selectors with up to two arguments. The following will all fire correctly:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action3:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

for handlers as such:

```
- (void)action1 {
  //...
}
- (void)action2:(UIControl *)control {
  //...
}
- (void)action3:(UIControl *)control event:(UIEvent *)event {
  //...
}
```

In most cases, the event parameter is unused in applications, so you'll typically only see examples of `action1` or `action2` in source code. For your particular usage, you'll want to use the `action2` style. You can change the parameter type to `UIButton *` or any other subclass of `UIControl` if you want.